# DTO Binding Lifecycle on jDTO Binder

Tags: java, dto, jdto

I'm trying hook up a lifecycle call on jDTO Binder so my DTO can perform some initialization before it gets populated, here is my callback method:

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    //here is the initialization
    logger.info("I'm getting called");
}
```

But for some reason this callback method does not get called, how would be the proper way to configure such a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the jDTO Binder documentation, you will find a working example on how to configure lifecycle callbacks.

Please see the following [jDTO Binder Manual](http://www.jdto.org/media/manual/jdto.html#sec31)